# How to keep some custom attributes when generating a proxy with svcutils?

Tags: wcf, proxy, protobuf-net

I use the following command to generate a proxy class for a WCF service :

```
svcutil.exe" /out:C:\SomePath\.... /n:*,Internal.FooNameSpace 
   http://localhost/MyService.svc
```

The following class :

```
[ProtoContract]
[ServiceContract]
public class Foo 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Becomes :

```
public partial class Foo : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{            
        private string BarField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Bar
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BarField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.BarField = value;
            }
        }        
}
```

Is there a way to keep some specific attributes on the generated class ? (eg : `ProtoMember` in this case). I could off course hack the proxy but it create maintenance problems.

Comment: You are right, this isn't exactly what is generated. I made some mistake while anonymising my proxy. I edited question.

Comment: I probably need another cup of coffee. Thanks for your answer, i'm reading it.

Comment: about to add another option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding that as a service reference, then nope: there's no way to retain that information - it simply isn't in the WCF endpoint.

IIRC, though, the WCF code-gen *does* actually come up with incremental `Order` values when you have multiple properties - i.e. the next property would be `[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order = 1)]`, then `2` etc. So one option is to **in a different file** (the beauty of `partial class`), define (in the same namespace, etc) additional info about your type:

```
[ProtoContract(DataMemberOffset = 1)]
public partial class Foo { }
```

What this means is: when processing `[DataMember]`, add `1` to every value - that means that you *should* get the required 1,2,3,4... and everything will be fine, and you haven't had to change the code.

Alternatively, you can be explicit:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoPartialMember(1, nameof(Foo.Bar))]
[ProtoPartialMember(2, nameof(Foo.AnotherProp))]
public partial class Foo { }
```

This gives you a lot more flexibility to specify nuance about the properties.

As another alterative, you can configure everything at runtime:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Foo), false)
    .Add(1, nameof(Foo.Bar))
    .Add(2, nameof(Foo.AnotherProp));
    // or AddField to get the ValueMember that you can use to set
    // fine-grained control
```

Finally, you can just *ship the data contract dll*, and tell svctil to use the types it already contains. You do this with the `/reference:<file path>` command-line switch, or there's a similar feature when using the UI tools (that lets you choose from the available dlls).

---

As a second "finally" (because one is not enough): you could describe the data instead as a .proto schema, and just tell the recipient to do the codegen locally and tell svcutil to exclude it (`/excludeType:` or `/reference:`). Note that the [*in progress rewrite* of "protogen"](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/) *does not* currently include `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember]` attributes, but I could get that added *today* if it would be useful.

Comment: Regarding solution with `DataMemberOffset` : I had to decorate partial class with `[DataContract]` attribute in order to make it work. With only `[ServiceContract]` it does not work (serializer return an empty byte array)

Comment: @tigrou fair enough; I assumed (incorrectly, it seems) that `Foo` would already be marked `[DataContract]`